# Creating datasets from normal and mixed gaussians:is this correct?

Tags: matlab

I have the following problem:

suppose x1, x2 are independent observations following a normal PDF, mean 0 and std 1.

OR suppose x1, x2 are independent observations coming from a miture of Gaussians PDF 0.3*N(−2,1)+...
0.7*N(2, 1)}

I am trying to plot (and later on classify) 1000 observations of each one of them.

I have programmed the following code in matlab 2020a:

```
    N=1000;

    x1=normrnd(0,1,[1, N]);
    x2=normrnd(0,1,[1, N]);

    g = gmdistribution([-2;2],1,[.3;.7]);
    c1=random(g,1000);
    c2=random(g,1000);

    figure()
    plot(x1,x2,'r*');
    hold on
    plot(c1,c2,'b*');
    title('X_1 and X_2');
    xlabel('X_1'); ylabel('X_2');
```

Does this seem correct?

Thanks

Pridu

Comment: Seems OK. Why do you worry it's not OK?

Comment: You can do `histogram(x1)` and `histogram(c1)` to verify that the numbers drawn are distributed in the way you expect.

Comment: I was wondering that since for independent observations x1, x2 the PDF F(x1, x2) is their product PDF F(x1)*F(x2), shall I sample from random(F(x1)) and random(F(x2)), or from random(F(x1,x2))?

Comment: If they're independent, you can sample them independently from their respective distributions. You only need to sample from a 2D distribution if the components are dependent.

Comment: Ok, got it! many thanks